# How to extract a date from Excel into Scilab?

Tags: excel, date, scilab

I want to use data from an Excel doc in Scilab.
And one of the data that i want to use are dates in DD/MM/YYYY.

But I have a problem when I want to read it in Scilab.
For exemple, if in the sheet my date is 20/11/2020, in Scilab it converts to 44155.

I tried to use the datevec() function, but it returns me 120.   11.   21.   0.   0.   0.

The problem for me comes from the data exctraction. I don't know what Scilab does when it reads the Excel doc.
And I don't want to change the format of the date on Excel, so I'm kinda stuck now.

If you have a solution, please help me T-T.

Comment: Udapte : I tried to put the date in Excel in this format : 20-nov.-20 and it changed nothing in Scilab. So Scilab seems to recognize that it's a date, but I don't know what operation it does on it

Comment: *if in the sheet my date is 20/11/2020, in Scilab it converts to 44155* In Excel dates are integer values. Number 1 is 01 Jan 1900, number 2 is 2 Jan 1900 and so on. 44155 is, actually, 20 nov 2020. But [looking at this](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/datenum.html)  it says *By default, the serial day 1 corresponds to 1-Jan-0000* so scilab is counting 44155 from 1 Jan 0000, not 1900 as Excel. That explains why it returns the year 120

Comment: You could get the year, the month and the day in Excel columns and then use [datenum](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/datenum.html) to convert them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted in comments, in cells with a date format, actual dates are stored as numbers, in Excel as in other spreadsheet softwares like Libreoffice/Calc and so.
Once you have read the spreadsheet with scilab and you have got serialized dates as a single number for each one, you must convert them with the following code, that uses your 2020-11-20 example stored as 44155:

```
--> [Y,M,D] = datevec(44155+693960) 
 Y  = 
   2020.
 M  = 
   11.
 D  = 
   20.
```

As a general rule, add the constant 693960 to your numerical dates from Excel. This constant is just the shift between the Excel's origin for dates, and the Scilab/datenum/datevec one.

`datevec` is "vectorized". That means that if you have read a whole column of dates in Excel, you have got a whole column of corresponding numbers. Then you can provide them to datevec() with a single call, as in the following:

```
--> N = (44155:44175)';
--> [Y,M,D] = datevec(N+693962); [N Y M D]
 ans  =
   44155.   2020.   11.   22.
   44156.   2020.   11.   23.
   44157.   2020.   11.   24.
   44158.   2020.   11.   25.
   44159.   2020.   11.   26.
   44160.   2020.   11.   27.
   44161.   2020.   11.   28.
   44162.   2020.   11.   29.
   44163.   2020.   11.   30.
   44164.   2020.   12.   1. 
   44165.   2020.   12.   2. 
   44166.   2020.   12.   3. 
   44167.   2020.   12.   4. 
   44168.   2020.   12.   5. 
   44169.   2020.   12.   6. 
   44170.   2020.   12.   7. 
   44171.   2020.   12.   8. 
   44172.   2020.   12.   9. 
   44173.   2020.   12.   10.
   44174.   2020.   12.   11.
   44175.   2020.   12.   12.
```

and then to print (or get) dates as strings in standard international format:

```
--> mprintf(""%d-%02d-%02d\n", Y,M,D) // or msprintf(..) to get strings instead of printing
2020-11-22
2020-11-23
2020-11-24
2020-11-25
2020-11-26
2020-11-27
2020-11-28
2020-11-29
2020-11-30
2020-12-01
2020-12-02
2020-12-03
2020-12-04
2020-12-05
2020-12-06
2020-12-07
2020-12-08
2020-12-09
2020-12-10
2020-12-11
2020-12-12
```